# Front door, custom domain resource reference ID of routes need correcting

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-custom-domain

In Azure, we have front door and route with custom domains, and the origin groups blade is giving following issue about “The following resource IDs are not match.” for instance :-

```
Error resource reference ID: /subscriptions/sid/resourcegroups/rg-wrong/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/fd-my/customDomains/tacn
Suggested resource reference ID: /subscriptions/sid/resourcegroups/rg-correct/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/fd-my/customDomains/tacn

The route has been given a wrong list of resource reference ID’s, containing the wrong resource-group name. With references like this :-
“/subscriptions/sid/resourcegroups/rg-wrong/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/fd-my/customDomains/tacn”
Rather than like this : “/subscriptions/sid/resourcegroups/rg-correct/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/fd-my/customDomains/tacn”
```

And that was done with az cli call like this :-

```
az afd route create --custom-domains $customDomainIds …
```

The $customDomainIds, had the resource reference ID’s using the “rg-wrong” value rather than the “rg-correct” value.

Is there a way of correcting this via the portal UI ?

Comment: It seems like there is no possibility of doing it via the portal. You need to delete the existed route using CLI and create it with the required one. @judek

Answer (score 0):

To update the route via Portal, go to your front-end profile under a specific resource group, `settings >> Front Door Manager >> Edit route` as shown below.

[image]

Once you visited the above path, it redirects you to the page that updates the route details as per your requirement.

[image]

But you cannot edit all the route details via portal.
***As a workaround***, use Azure CLI to delete the existed route and create a new route with the correct details.

[image]

[`az afd route delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/route?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-route-delete)

```bash
az afd route delete --profile-name newj --endpoint-name newp --route-name newroute --resource-group xxx
```

[image]

[`az afd route create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/afd/route?view=azure-cli-latest#az-afd-route-create)